# Is it normal for Bluetooth settings to always read "searching for and can be discovered by Bluetooth devices"?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, bluetooth

My windows 8.1 bluetooth settings screen always reads "Your PC is searching for and can be discovered by Bluetooth devices."

[image: Windows 8.1 Bluetooth settings screen]

Is this normal? What if I just want to have my keyboard paired to my laptop, but not have my laptop continuously searching for new devices? Is there a way to turn off the "searching" part?

Currently, the only way to turn off that message is to turn off Bluetooth altogether.

Or is there not really a difference between "searching for devices" and being paired with devices? I.e. are the signals sent out by my laptop to pair same as the signals sent out to search for devices, and there aren't actually any "extra" signals sent specifically to search for devices?

(Not a networking guy)

Comment: Similar behaviour in Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will always say that, yes. But it's only true as long as you are on that screen, while the message is visible. Once you close it, your device is no longer discoverable, but will still communicate with paired devices.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I'm still curious as to if bluetooth "searching" signals are different than "pairing" signals, though!